# How do I track user sessions in my own middleware in django?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

Django's session middleware only assigns a session key when the session is first saved. How do I use the session key in my own middleware?

Answer (score 0):

The first request of a new session does not have a session key. In order to track user sessions from the very first request, use your own custom identifier, something like this:

```
import base32_crockford
import uuid
...
MY_SESSION_KEY='my_custom_session_key'
...
 def process_request(self, request):
        if MY_SESSION_KEY not in request.session:
            if request.session.session_key is None:
                my_key = base32_crockford.encode(uuid.uuid4()).lower()
                request.session[MY_SESSION_KEY] = my_key
            else:
                request.session[MY_SESSION_KEY] = request.session.session_key

        session_instance = request.session[MY_SESSION_KEY]
```

This code will use the existing session key if it exists, or create a new random key (I encode with base32 for easier copy-pasting of the values). You can use the string value of the UUID directly if you prefer.

Comment: Please, add this to your original post and remove this answer.

Comment: I answered my own question, in case others have a similar situation.